# Humans In A Fantasy World

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, fantasy-races, alternate-worlds, humanoid

I am currently building a fantasy world that contains humans inside of it, but the problem I currently face or wonder about is what physical differences there might be in my world compared to the ones in our world. There are some differences I have already places down that are more common in different ethnic groups. For Example white hair, and violet eyes that was bred into one population of islander humans, and the Asians of the world being large and broad like the Norse were due to their nomadic lifestyle and access to nutrients and milk on the planes. Additionally there are humans that are born with silver or true grey colored eyes which is a rare ancestral trait from millennia ago from the first humans to develop. There is a possible combination of silver (or White) hair and grey eyes that is seen as a bad omen or the traits of a serial killer due to a several notorious killers and infamous people having the trait. There is also a rare mutation caused by ingesting a flower that causes hermaphroditic traits and golden irises that may or may not have vertically slit pupils when consumed while pregnant or as an infant. But that's more augmented than a natural trait.

Now onto the question which is what differences we might see in humans due to the place where they first evolved before migrating south in my world? In my world humans evolved in the north in the tundra in a giant 400 diameter crater surrounded by volcanic peaks and mountains to for a habitual 'bowl' in the frigid north. The area was highly geologically active with most of the water located in the actual bowl being warm and host spring like. Also due to the warmth of the water and the slight warmth in the ground there is a difference between the tundra air the flows between the peaks slowly and causes heavy fog and rainfall. essentially creating a temperate rain-forest zone within the tundra. Now humans would also be able to see the auroras whenever cloud cover wasn't heavy and likely had periods of total night and total day like in some more northern countries of the world.

There is also a network of hollows that are called the under dark that were formed by both natural and unnatural processes (imagine sort of like gears of war but much more filled with life) filled with luminescent bio crystals colonies that keep a mild temperature environment with high humidity in the hollows. Though in such a geologically active region these hollows would likely not exist or only be usable in more stable areas of the 'bowl'. Light levels down in the hollows is like that a of rainy day whenever they're illuminated by the crystals so they are lower light conditions in the under dark. So likely the first persons to exist would have been fair skinned, eyed, and haired. But what other things might they have?

Here is a space view of the planet that I friend made for me if any of you wanted to know what the landmasses looked like.[image]

Comment: What is a giant 400 diameter crater?

Comment: Hi and welcome! If you haven't already, please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help] and find out [what WB.SE is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about).  You've got the basics of an interesting world here, but your question is kind of all over the place -- it "lacks focus".  We'll need you to edit this question so that you focus on a single worldbuilding problem or issue that you're facing. You are asking for a (very likely) long list of things...

Comment: ... and that kind of query is not a good fit here. I'm going to vote to close your question in order to give you some time to edit it. Please focus on *one specific issue at a time*; also, please present your question neatly. Try to get your spelling in order, fix the issue with the size of your crater. We'll also need to know some things about the planet & universe itself. Describe what you mean by "underdark"; is there magic involved; are the Laws of Nature different; etc. Also, take a look into "endorheic basics" and the acidic nature of volcanic lakes.

Comment: Oh, and before I forget! You are certainly allowed (and encouraged!) to ask other questions about your world! You just have to ask one question at a time.

Comment: *"What differences we might see in humans due to the place where they first evolved?"* Differences *from what?* Animals which evolved in a volcanic creater in the tundra would most definitely not look like actual humans, who are, after all, apes adapted to life in the hot and flat African savannah. *We* evolved to be very good at shedding heat and sacrificed musculuar strength for the ability to run for a long time. Both characteristics are not likely to be selected in a crater in the tundra.